My character eyes don't move with rig
I tried a lot of ways on the My character eyes don't move with rig.
There is my Blender file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/17zLi0ygqARnAObxWQSMVHP7-urf4hQqF/view?usp=sharing


It looks like it's rather the head that doesn't follow correctly, see all the vertex group a head vertex is assigned to when it should be assigned to DEF-spine.006 only:

You could select all the head vertices and remove from all groups:

Then assign to DEF-spine.006:


Oh my god! Thank you so much! You made my day :((((
